# Conditional Formatting (Google sheet)

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, formula

I am trying to format a group of cells but I need a custom formula for when the value of a cell is greater than the value of the cell in its column of a specific row it needs to be highlighted
(The highlighted value reference point in the group is in the same row)
Please help

I tried to highlight by using the default option on each column but there are way too many rows

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your exact spreadsheet. Let's say your range goes from A1:Z, and that the column of reference is column E (from each row). Then you can set this formula to:

```
=A1 > $E1
```

Change A1 to the first cell of your range and $E1 with the first corresponding column of the first row of the rage (if you start row 3, then put $E3 -- and change the letter ;) )

Let me know if this works for you!